# Weak formulation of $\Delta^{2}u=f$ with boundary conditions $u=\Delta u =0$.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces, boundary-value-problem, weak-derivatives

Let $U\subset\mathbb{R}^{n}$ be an open subset (with sufficiently smooth boundary) and consider the boundary value problem
$$\begin{cases}\Delta^{2}u=f \ \text{on $U$} \\ u=\Delta u=0 \ \text{on $\partial U$} \end{cases}.$$
To find a unique weak solution, I want to apply the Riesz representation theorem or Lax-Milgram theorem to an appropriate Sobolev space. My problem is finding this appropriate Sobolev space, that is, I'm trying to find the weak formulation of the above problem.

I multiplied the above equation with a sufficiently smooth test function $v$ and found that
\begin{align*}
\int_{U}\Delta^{2}u \cdot v&=\int_{\partial U}\frac{\partial\Delta u}{\partial n}\cdot v-\int_{\partial U}\Delta u\cdot\frac{\partial v}{\partial n}+\int_{U}\Delta u\cdot\Delta v\\
&=\int_{\partial U}\frac{\partial\Delta u}{\partial n}\cdot v+\int_{U}\Delta u\cdot\Delta v.
\end{align*}
I have seen that $H^{2}(U)\cap H_{0}^{1}(U)$ is the Sobolev space we are looking for, but how do I deduce that? Is there a general approach?

Of course we need $v\in H^{2}(U)$ in order to apply $\Delta$ to it. Furthermore, it looks like we are forcing the integral on the boundary to be zero by requiring $v=0$ on $\partial U$, i.e. $v\in H_{0}^{1}(U)$. Also, in order to apply the above mentioned theorems, one needs $u$ and $v$ to lie in the same Sobolev space. But if $u\in H^{2}(U)\cap H_{0}^{1}(U)$ is a weak solution, then we do not have $\Delta u=0$ on $\partial U$.

Comment: I'm a bit confused. Are you only trying to prove uniqueness of the solution $u$? Or are you trying to find some sort of formulation of the solution as well?

Comment: @K.defaoite I'm trying to find an expression that the weak solution must satisfy (i.e. an equation involving some bilinear form on some Sobolev space). After that, the existence + uniqueness is routine.

Comment: Ok, I understand now. Unfortunately I have not studied Sobolev spaces. I was going to recommend the Maximum Principle, but you are probably already aware of this.

Comment: The way I see it there is no natural setting for a weak formulation that includes the boundary condition in a weak sense. This is due to the trace operator not being well defined on $\Delta u$ for $u\in H^2$. However for sufficiently smooth solutions you will get the boundary condition back by reversing the steps you did to obtain the weak formulation.

Comment: @K.defaoite: A small side note: Using a maximum principle is a very subtle matter for fourth order operators, since such operators do not satisfy the maximum principle under the same general conditions as second order operators do.

Comment: The following does not answer your question, but it might be worthwhile to mention it anyway: finding a weak formulation and then applying Lax-Milgram to the problem seems a bit over-complicated in the given situation: your problem is equivalent to solving twice the boundary value problem $\Delta u = f$ with zero Dirichlet boundary conditions, so unique solvability of your problem follows from unique solvability of $\Delta u = f$ with Dirichlet b.c.